# Usage of EOF in C

Tags: c

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOtVw.png)

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
  int c;
  printf("Enter any charachter!: ");
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
    printf("%d\n", (c = getchar()) != EOF);
  }
}
```

I've tried to test out EOF in C and I'm having a difficult time with it. I've wanted to get the value of EOF and found out that it is `-1`.

I wrote a simple program using `getchar()` and `putchar().`

I have added the screenshot of the program and output. Output doesn't make any sense to me.

As you can see I'm trying to get a character and display it using `getchar()` and `putchar()`. And I'm trying to print out the value of the condition used in the while loop. To check the EOF I'm deliberately entering `-1` as input. `putchar()` prints out `-1` and then the final printf statement confuses me. I enter `-1` for `getchar()` but `1` displayed meaning c is not equal to EOF. But I thought `-1` is EOF.
And I don't understand why `11` is also displayed. I'm using `codeblocks` IDE.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Please post code as text - not a screenshot.  2) You're calling "getchar()" *TWICE IN THE SAME LOOP*.  Probably not what you intended ;)

Comment: Entering `-1` as input will result in `getchar` returning the ASCII code of `-` and then the ASCII code of `1`, you're mixing up characters and integers. `EOF` can be generated by pressing Ctrl+D (Linux) or Ctrl+Z (Windows).

Answer (score 3):

`EOF` isn’t a character, and it isn’t read from the stream.  It’s just the return value indicating that there is no more input on that stream.  You can signal an `EOF` by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> on *nix or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows.

Comment: It should be noted that control-D results in EOF only at the beginning of a line or when pressed twice. It does not actually generate EOF. Rather, it sends the contents of the keyboard input buffer to the program. The input handling software interprets a read request that receives zero characyers as EOF. So control-D when no characters are pending causes EOF behavior. Control-D when characters are pending just sends them immediately instead of when enter is pressed, without causing EOF behavior.

Comment: That was exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score -1):

getchar takes input one character(byte) at a time. so when you input '-1' it is treated as a character array input and first getchar takes input only '-' and second one takes input '1'. Thus you are not getting your desired output. Also putchar is designed to print one character at a time. So it might not work properly too. You can change your code following way to make it work.

```
int c;

while(scanf("%d", &c)!=EOF) { //to ensure there is some input value as scanf will return EOF when input stream finishes.

    printf("%d\n", c);
    if(c == EOF) {
        printf("c is equal to EOF\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very broken, `scanf()` can return EOF, but not set a target variable to it, that's just made up and there's no way you tested this code.

Comment: Thank you. Fixed the bug @jens